# Python : How to pass a value to a variable that is a function...?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm like many others here new to Python and programming in general. Hope someone can help.

I have a dictionary like this:

```
dictionary = {
    'key1' : fun1(),
    'key2' : fun2(),
     ...
     }
val = dictionary.get('key2')
```

I now want to use `val` to call `fun2()`. How do I pass arguments to `val`? Let's say `fun2(x, y)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here is firstly remove the parentheses from the functions in your dictionary. The reason you need to do this is because otherwise you are calling them and the returned value will be stored instead.

Then after you define `val` as before, you should be able to use it like you would the normal function name as it now points to `fun2`:

```
val(x, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

don't call your functions as the values, but stick the functions themselves in there

```
dictionary = {
            'key1' : fun1,#no parens
            'key2' : fun2,#no parens
             ...
            }
val = dictionary.get('key2')(x,y)
```